# How to convert different row result by the similar id to different columns with unique id in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-17

I have two table that have "1:*" relation. I want to join two table and merge all rows with similar id into one row and different columns that have the same row value.

In order to my result in ssms 17 is :

```
table1.id    table2.tag 
------------------------
1            <value a>
1            <value b>
1            <value c>
2            <value d>
2            <value e>
```

I want this result:

```
table1.id    C1.table2.tag    C2.table2.tag    C3.table2.tag
------------------------------------------------------------
1            <value a>        <value b>        <value c>
2            <value d>        <value e>        null
```

Answer (score 1):

If tags are not more then you can do *conditional* aggregation :

```
select id, 
       max(case when seq = 1 then tag end) as tag_1,
       max(case when seq = 2 then tag end) as tag_2,
       max(case when seq = 3 then tag end) as tag_3
from (select t1.id, t2.*, row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by t2.tag) as seq
      from table1 t1 inner join
           table2 t2
           on t2.id = t1.id
     ) t
group by id;
```

If table has more tags then you need Dynamic Pivot.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend putting each tag in a separate column.  An alternative is to combine the tags into a single column.

For instance:

```
select t1.table1_id,
       string_agg(t2.tag, ',') as tags
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.id = t1.table2_id
group by t1.table1_id;
```

Then you don't have to worry about the maximum number of tags for a given id or using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon for your answer, but I need this value on columns. I have a lot of id and for each id I have max 5 tag.

Comment: @Elmojioo . . . Then Yogesh has the right answer for you